# How to get the sub string part from a directory with shell command

Tags: shell, shell-scripting

I would need to extract only last 2 part from the following directory path using shell command

"Android/2.1/Packages/test/debug/"

Expected out put: /test/debug

This path is the dynamic where it would change with different path value as such
"Android/2/Pipeline/Packages/test/debug/"

I couldn't find the specific regular expression which can extract the last 2 part even rest of path value keeps change, ie only to get '/test/debug'

Appreciate if any one can help on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's many approaches, you could try (replacing pwd with something suitable for your use case):

```
echo /$(basename $(dirname $(pwd)))/$(basename $(pwd))
```

or

```
pwd | awk -F/ '{print "/" $(NF-1) "/" $(NF)}'
```

And probably countless other ways . . .

Answer (score 0):

The shell can do this indirectly with variable modifiers `%`, `%%`, `#` and `##`.
These remove the trailing or leading match for the pattern given.  Note that the
pattern is a shell *glob*, not a regular expression.

The following example will print the last two path elements, with or without the optional trailing `/`

```
$ in="Android/2/Pipeline/Packages/test/debug/"
$ echo $( t=${in%/} && t=${t%/*/*} && echo ${in##$t} )
/test/debug/
```